# Is it possible to transfer Pokemon from previous 3DS Pokemon games to Sun/Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation, pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-seventh-generation

I own three Pokemon games on 3DS: Y, OmegaRuby and Moon. I've got some nice Pokemon in first two. Is it somehow possible for me to transfer my Pokemon to Pokemon Moon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is Pokémon Bank. It's the same procedure like in Generation 6, but the Update for Pokémon Bank will release first in January, so currently the answer is actually **NO**.

A useful link can be found [here](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/pokmon-bank-wont-be-compatible-with-sun-and-moon-until-early-2017).
Matter, that trading them back won't be possible. You also cannot trade Gen6 back into Gen5 Editions.